# Kotlin function argument without type annotation

Tags: kotlin

On Kotlin, Arguments of a function require their type annotation when defining the method.

In my case, I have two classes from an interface.

```
interface Base{
    fun method()
}

class DervA():Base{
    fun override method(){
        ...
    }
}

class DervB():Base{
    fun override method(){
        ...
    }
}
```

And, I hope to call their methods from other function like

```
fun test_method(inst){
    inst.method()
}
```

But, Kotlin compiler complains "a type annotation is required on a value parameter" .

Should I define "test_method" for each of the classes ?

```
fun test_method_for_DervA(inst:DervA){
    inst.method()
}

fun test_method_for_DervB(inst:DervB){
    inst.method()
}
```

Do you have any smarter way for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just do

```
fun testMethod(inst: Base) {
    inst.method()
}
```

Since both `DervA` and `DervB` are `Base`s, they can also be passed to `testMethod` and their overridden `method` will be called. That's one of the fundamental principles of OOP.

---

Note that if `method` and `testMethod` have the same return type, you can shorten it to

```
fun testMethod(inst: Base) = inst.method()
```

Comment: A shorter one: `val testMethod = Base::method`

Comment: @chris well, that's not really equivalent. `fun` defines a method, and in your case `testMethod` is assigned a value of type `KFunction`.

Comment: Not completely equivalent, but still usable through the same syntax.

Comment: Unless Java interop is a concern. I also find functions are usually easier to reason about than function references in properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun test_method(inst){
    inst.method()
}
```

What, in your opinion, could help the compiler derive the type of `inst` and decide whether `inst` even has `.method()`?

I suppose you need `inst: Base` declared somewhere for inference to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature isn't correct, the compiler doesn't have a chance to know the parameter's type, there's no inference available in this situation:

```
fun test_method(inst)
```

It's necessary to declare it like this:

```
fun test_method(inst: Base)
```